# Created a gz backup of a server and when I extract it I get a huge blank file

Tags: backup, gzip

I gzipped a folder in an old server that included all of the sites served. That server does not exist anymore and I needed some info from the backup but when I extract the backup (a 26GB file) I only get a 28GB blank file that says "Document" under OSX and no program says it's corrupted or anything. Could I recover any info inside this file or is it a lost cause? I tried anyways everything listed [here](http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt) and got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `gzip` is a pure compression tool. It cannot archive a folder on its own. So what you most probably did is you created a gzipped tarball (via `tar czf file.tar.gz folder`). To unpack it, you need to tell `tar` to unpack it: `tar xzf file.tar.gz` or if you already unpacked the file with `gzip` you can call `tar xf file.tar`.

Comment: I get these errors when I tried the commands you mentioned on either the original file or the extracted result tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Comment: This is what the file command tells me about the file backupaugust.gz: gzip compressed data, was "phpinfo.php", from Unix, last modified: Tue Feb 22 14:55:42 2011

Comment: And what does `file` say about the unzipped "Document"?